# Ajax post request to google NLP

Tags: json, ajax, api, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

Im trying to do a post request to [GCP Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-tutorial) for sentiment analysis.

When I try the data format on the code explorer on google it works fine but when I run it on a html page I get an error that reads

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[type]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[type]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[content]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[content]' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[type]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[type]' could not be found in request message."
          },
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[content]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[content]' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Testing sentiment Analysis </h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var APIKEY = "AN API KEY";

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        url         : "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSentiment?key="+APIKEY,
        data        :   {
                            "document": {
                                "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
                                "content": "Hello I am great"
                            },
                            "encodingType": "UTF8",
                        },
        success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                alert(res['message']);
        },
        error: function(res) {
                console.log(res['message']);
                alert(res);
        },
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
A colleague has pointed me to the MISTAKE I was making. We have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send the request. The code should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    url         : "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntitySentiment?key=YOUR-API-KEY", 
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data        : 
                    JSON.stringify({
                        "document": {
                            "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
                            "language": "en",
                            "content": "Hola Victor"

                        },
                        "encodingType": "UTF8"}),
    success     : function(_result){ 

        if (_result) { 
            alert('SUCCESS');
        } else {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    },

    error       : function(_result){

    }
});
```

I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Victor. I still get the error `"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[type]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[type]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document[content]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'document[content]' could not be found in request message.",`

Comment: I hace made it work with Curl and Postman. For some reason it fails with ajax

Comment: What was your CURL code? (unable to install postman on my PC due to admin issues)

Comment: create a file named `request.json` with this content: `{
  "document": 
  {
    "content": "Hello dear",
    "language": "en",
    "type": "PLAIN_TEXT"
  },
  "encodingType": "UTF8"
}` and in the same folder run curl: `curl -v -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSentiment?key=YOUR-API-KEY \
    --data-binary @request.json`